# Download single file with multiple connection in java?

Tags: java

I'm doing a project on java download manager.i want to download a single file(which is in some website) with multiple connections(just like download Managers do,example-IDM).Is this possible in java ?.if yes please help me how can i implement that.if you people have any sample code then please post.Thank you in Advance..Have a Rocking Future.

Comment: sorry...no code for you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here are a couple of hints. No code though.

A multi-connection download manager relies on the support for the [`Accept-Ranges`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.5) header in the [HTTP 1.1](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616.html) specification. Servers would use this header to indicate that they support sending of partial responses to the client.

HTTP clients use the [`Range`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.35) header in the request to obtain partial responses. All partial responses will carry a [`Content-Range`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.16) header.

A multi-connection download manager would make multiple connections to a server supporting this feature. Each connection would issue it's own range of headers to download. The responses would then be collated in the necessary order to obtain the desired file. The size of the ranges can be pre-calculated using an initial HTTP HEAD request, which returns the actual size of the file in the `Content-Length` response header; the task of downloading the file may now be split into suitable chunks.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend reading about [Segmented downloading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmented_downloading), thinking of a way to implement it in Java and than asking concrete questions if you have any.